# Disable select input if option value exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to disable the select box if Free Shipping is available.

```
<select name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method">
    <option value="">Select shipping</option>
    <option value="free_shipping">Free Shipping</option>
    <option value="international_delivery">International: $30.00</option>
</select>
```

I've tried this (without knowing if it would work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("option").val() == "free_shipping") {
        $("select").prop("disabled");
    }
});
```

And then assuming on form submit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $("select", this).prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: So if someone picks free shipping from that select field, the entire select field should become disabled? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No its so when the customer reaches a threshold on an order they get free delivery, but the loop doesn't remove the other shipping methods.

Comment: What's the loop you speak of?

Comment: It's one that prints the select form options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$.has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('#shipping_method').has('option[value="free_shipping"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mmvje/)

Answer (score 1):

select the select

```
$('#shipping_method').change(function(){
    var j = $(this);
    if(j.val() == 'free_shipping') {
        j.attr('disabled', true);
    }    
    else {
        j.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: `attr` is not recommended for changing runtime properties like `disabled` or `checked` instead use `props()`